# MongoDb: Insert Document in collection only if collection has no newer document since point in time

Tags: mongodb

I want to depict the following use case using MongoDb:

I want to read from a collection and memorize that particular point in time.
When writing the next time to that collection, I want to not be able to write a new document, if another document has been added to that collection in between.
Using a `timestamp` property on the documents would be ok.

Is this possible?

Comment: Trying to understand your use case. What do you mean by memorizing the time of read ? Do you save the last read from collection time somewhere ? How/Where is this time tracked ?

Comment: Time of the read is can indeed be the time when the collection has been read or it can be a document property to track when the document was written. Documents will never get updated, only newer will be added. Plain MongoDb (including 4.0) + Node.js native driver should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Assume at the time of reading, your most recent timestamp on a document is `oldTimestamp`:

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {timestamp: {$gt: oldTimestamp}},
    new: true, // Return modified / inserted document
    upsert: true, // Update if match found, insert otherwise
    update: {
         $setOnInsert: {..your document...}
    }
})
```

This will not insert your document if another document is inserted between your read and write operation.

However, this won't let you know that the document is inserted or not directly.

You should compare returned document with your proposed document to find that out.

In case using nodejs driver, the correct pattern should be:

```
collection.findAndModify(criteria[, sort[, update[, options]]], callback)
```

According to the [example](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html), our query should be:

```
db.collection('test').findAndModify(
  {timestamp: {$gt: oldTimestamp}}, // query, timestamp is a property of your document, often set as the created time
  [['timestamp','desc']],  // sort order
  {$setOnInsert: {..your document..}}, // replacement, replaces only the field "hi"
  {
      new: true,
      upsert: true
  }, // options
  function(err, object) {
      if (err){
          console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
      }else{
          console.dir(object);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: this returns `MongoError: bad sort specification`

Comment: may be you're using some bugging framework? This is raw query executing on Mongo console flawlessly

Comment: I'm using the Node.js driver 3.1

Comment: Nodejs driver require a sort specified, read my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, using a `timestamp` property in every document. You can take a look at the [Mongoose Pre Save path validation hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) . Using this hook, you can write something like this.

```
YourSchema.path('timestamp').validate(function(value, done) {
  this.model(YourSchemaModelName).count({ timestamp: {$gt : value} }, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
    // if count exists and not zero hence document is found with greater timestamp value
    done(!count);
});
}, 'Greater timestamp already exists');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to do some sort of optimistic locking at the collection level. I understand you are writing new documents but never updating existing ones in this collection?

You could add an index on the `timestamp` field, and your application would need to track the latest version of this value. Then, before attempting a new write you could lookup the latest value from the collection with a query like

`db.collection.find({}, {timestamp: 1, _id:0}).sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(1)`

which would project just the maximum `timestamp` value using a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) which is pretty efficient.

From that point on, it's up to your application logic to handle the 'conflict'.